# Powering an offset stacked array of pistons

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm attempting to power an array of pistons as shown. I've had a look around and can't find anything similar to my issue. I've tried repeaters in various setups but to no avail. I would use levers but I need to power them all concurrently

[image: Setup of Pistons that I'm trying to power]

Comment: Does it need to go past the 15 block limit for redstone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this? It can be powered and extended until the redstone limit.
[image: Pistons powered]